# How to get required index value from Map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have added the code into the Map using the below code
data includes featureCollection

```
function createMapInformation(data) {
    var myMap = new Map();
    if (hasValue(data)) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (i in data) {
                var dataProperty = data[i];
                myMap.set(i, dataProperty);
                for (j in dataProperty.properties.parameters) {
                    var field = j;
                    var value = dataProperty.properties.parameters[field];
                    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    var paramName = field;
                    var paramValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myMap;
}
```

Which data is look like this,

myMap =
0: 0 → Object { id: "10151", empId: "5I1101", type: "Store"}

1: 1 → Object { id: "10152", empId: "5I1102", type: "Store"}

​​​2: 2 → Object { id: "10153", empId: "5I1103", type: "Store"}

Now if i want the data from the 1 index then it should be return {id: "10152", empId: "5I1102", type: "Store"}
And want to pass index value from the loop also like

for (var i = 1; i <= myMap.size; i++) {
// Want to pass the index valie as i and it should be return as

- id: "10151", empId: "5I1101", type: "Store" etc
  }

I want to show the index wise data in the table, so the data is shown in the table format one by one

Comment: how are you mapping your values? To a variable ?, there shouldn't be a problem using the int.. `arrayValues[1]` for example

Comment: what is actually the problem by taking prototypes from `Map`? please add your code.

Comment: @Pogrindis i have updated the code, please check

Comment: @ravi right, the answer below will work and as mentioned by Nina.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`Map.prototype.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get):

```js
const m = new Map([
  [0, { id: "10151", empId: "5I1101", type: "Store"}],
  [1, { id: "10152", empId: "5I1102", type: "Store"}],
  [2, { id: "10153", empId: "5I1103", type: "Store"}],
]);
console.log(m.get(1));
```